# JavaScript Refresh Page after 5 Seconds on Checked Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, refresh, settimeout

Is there any way to **refresh a webpage every 5 seconds if checkbox is checked**?

For example, if the checkbox is unchecked, nothing happens, but if it's checked, then the function `refresh()` will make the page refresh every 5 seconds afterwards.

Here is the code I have so far, but this isn't working for some reason.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="autoRefresh" onclick="if(this.checked){refresh()}" checked>


function refresh() {
         setTimeout(function () { location.reload() }, 5000);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to temporarily store the information somewhere that checkbox is checked, say cookies or localStorage. Try out the following code:

```js
if(localStorage.getItem('doRefreshes')) {
  var x = setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
  }, 5000);
}

document.getElementById('autoRefresh').checked = !!localStorage.getItem('doRefreshes');

function toggleRefreshes(checked) {
  if(checked) {
    localStorage.setItem('doRefreshes', true)
    location.reload()
  } else {
    localStorage.removeItem('doRefreshes')
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="autoRefresh" onclick="toggleRefreshes(this.checked)">
```

Comment: I would suggest if possible to use a query string on the url ('?autorefresh=true') instead of any type of persistence. The query string is tied to the current tab, but persistent storage would affect multiple tabs opened to the same page, and a worse user experience. It's also the sort of state that cognitively works well when bookmarked either way.